# Return value of checkbox

Tags: checkbox

Can i Know what is the return value for checkbox? Is it string?

Comment: Please, give more details to your question to answer you properly. At least the programming language you are using to retrieve the checkbox value.

Comment: You have to be more specific than that, what framework? HTML?

Comment: i using jsp. i need to get the value after i have checked the checbox so that i can store into database.

Comment: i have the query like this: String sql = "update project_planning set newproposal = '"+newproposal+"', newchp = '"+newchp+"', newdesign = '"+newdesign+"', newsystem = '"+newsystem+"', newd_thesis = '"+newd_thesis+"', newf_thesis = '"+newf_thesis+"' where metric = ?";

Comment: it show an error newproposal, newchp, newdesign, newsystem, newd_thesis,newf_thesis cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Dolphin You can improve your answer rather than comment over and over. It's easier for people to know what's this about

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" name="newproposal" value="checked">`

Use the `value` attribute to specify the value that will be submitted.

On the server side with JSP, the value will be a String.  If it is checked, then the submitted String will be equal to the `value` attribute.  Use `String.equals` to decide whether it was checked.

`<%
boolean newproposal_checked = "checked".equals(request.getParameter("newproposal"));
%>`

Comment: <%@ include file = "connection.jsp"%>
<% String metric = request.getParameter("metric");
 String proposal = request.getParameter("proposal");
 String chp = request.getParameter("chp");
 String design = request.getParameter("design");
 String system = request.getParameter("system");
 String d_thesis = request.getParameter("d_thesis");
 String f_thesis = request.getParameter("f_thesis");

Comment: Connection conn = getConnected();
 ResultSet rs = null;
 PreparedStatement statement = null;
 PreparedStatement statement1 = null;
 statement1=conn.prepareStatement("insert into project_planning values (?,null,null,null,null,null,null)");
 statement1.clearParameters();
 statement1.setString(1,metric);
 statement1.executeUpdate();
 conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
 if(proposal != null){
  String newproposal = "1";
  }
 else{
  String newproposal = "0";
  }
   
 if(chp != null){
  String newchp = "1";
 }
 else{
  String newchp ="0";
  }

Comment: if(design != null){
  String newdesign = "1";
 }
 else{
  String newdesign = "0";
  }
  
 if(system != null){
  String newsystem = "1";
 }
 else{
  String newsystem = "0";
 }
 
 if(d_thesis != null){
  String newd_thesis = "1";
 }
 else{
  String newd_thesis = "0";
 }
 
 if(f_thesis != null){
  String newf_thesis = "1";
 }
 else{
  String newf_thesis = "0";
 }

Comment: String sql = "update project_planning set newproposal = '"+newproposal+"', newchp = '"+newchp+"', newdesign = '"+newdesign+"', newsystem = '"+newsystem+"', newd_thesis = '"+newd_thesis+"', newf_thesis = '"+newf_thesis+"' where metric = ?";
 statement=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 statement.clearParameters();
 statement.setString(1,metric);
 statement.executeUpdate();
 
%>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Succesfully Update!!!"); 
 self.location="combo.jsp";
    </script>

Comment: above here is my jsp code that i have done. But it come out with this error : newproposal, newchp, newdesign, newsystem, newd_thesis,newf_thesis cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Dolphin, you need to declare the variables outside the "if" blocks.  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScopeinablock.htm